# Replace All Function in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, replace

how can I replace all string in string varaiable like

```
dim str = "I am testing and testing and testing"
```

After replace with "and"

```
ReplaceAll(str,"and","or")
```

How can I replace all with case insentive not case sensative?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a case for regular expressions:

From http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2004/02/11/71188.aspx

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string myString = "find Me and replace ME";
string strReplace = "me";

myString = Regex.Replace(myString, "me", strReplace, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a VB/VBScript/.NET guy, and sleep-deprived to boot.

Comment: Regex.Replace("123456", ".", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) this return me empty string why?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim str As String = "I am testing and testing and testing"
    str = str.Replace("and", "or")
```

Comment: That's a case _sensitive_ replace.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the use of Regular Expression, as suggested by Matt and RQDQ, you can use the VB sugar, like:

```
Replace(expression, find, replacement, start, count, compare)
```

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).